# How can an Aura cmp receive values from LWC NavigationMixin?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, navigationmixin.navigate

Using LWC NavigationMixin to redirect user to an Aura component, is there a way for Aura cmp to receive values from the LWC? I am trying pass the values of `propertyValue` and `c__id` to the Aura cmp

```
    import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
    import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

    export default class MobileNavigation extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {  
    handleNavigate() {
        var compDefinition = {
            type: 'standard__component',
            componentDef: "c:TestAuraComponent",
            attributes: {
                propertyValue: "testValue"
            },
            state: {
                c__id: "test"
            }
        };
    }
```

I have already tried this and got `Action failed: c:TestAuraComponent$controller$getLabel [undefined is not an object (evaluating 'myLabel.state')]`:

```
getLabel : function(component, event, helper) {
    var myLabel = component.get("v.MobileNavigation");
    myLabel = myLabel.state.c__id;  
    component.set("v.buttonLabel", myLabel);
},
```

I suspect I am entering the wrong argument for cmp.get(), I have also tried ("v.compDefinition").

Update1: I realized that `pageReference is a special type of attribute and we don't have to create an attribute with the name pageReference.` I changed it to `var myLabel = component.get("v.pageReference");` and still I am getting undefined for `myLabel.state`

Update2: added `this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](compDefinition);` to invoke the method, still no luck

Update3: I can render a string like `myLabel = 'hello world';` just not `myLabel.state`. Looks like the problem is getting the state/attribute values.

Comment: Does your aura implements `isUrlAddressable` interface?

Comment: @SachinHooda I added `implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable"` and it seems to be working. Thanks